# How can I reach rootViewController on NavigationController from TabBar?

Tags: swift

I am coding a chat app. I want to fetch my messages on background. It will be continuous. Thats why I will use ***performFetchWithCompletionHandler*** (if you know better way you can offer me). My *rootViewController* is *tabBar*. But I have to use this code for other controller and I can't reach that controller from *AppDelegate*.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let tabbarController = window?.rootViewController as? CustomTabBarController{
        if let postController = tabbarController.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? PostsController{
            print("itsWorking")
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //This is my rootViewController

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let postsController = PostsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    let gezginController = GezginController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

    let homeNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: postsController)
    homeNavController.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
    homeNavController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home")

    navigationController?.pushViewController(gezginController, animated: true)
    gezginController.tabBarItem.title = "Gezgin"
    gezginController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "rocket")

    viewControllers = [homeNavController,gezginController]
}
```

I want to reach to *PostController* from *AppDelegate*. But you have to know that *PostController* is CollectionView and I am using layout for that. That's why I cant use like *PostController*(layout: layout) on *AppDelegate*. Actually I dont want that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the application's shared window:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let tabbarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? CustomTabBarController,
        let postController = tabbarController.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? PostsController {
        print("great success")
    }

}
```